# quick question on ascending chain condition for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that if $R$ is a commutative ring with an identity in which every ideal if finitely generated then it satisfies the ascending chain condition. *Just* wondering if the converse is also true?

Comment: See theorem 1.7 here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/noetherianmod.pdf (The commutativity is not really needed, but it's the best handout I could find on short notice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Rings that satisfy the ascending chain condition on ideals, are called Noetherian. A (commutative unital) ring is Noetherian if and only if every ideal is finitely generated.

**Proof of** *"If $R$ satisfies the ascending chain condition then every ideal is finitely generated"*.

Take an ideal $I\subset R$. Suppose $R$ has ascending chain condition but $I$ is not finitely generated. Choose $f_0\in I$ and look at the ideal $(f_0)$. Now $I\neq (f_0)$ (because $I$ is not finitely generated) so there exists $f_1\in I$ but $f_1\notin I_0$. The consider the ideal $(f_0, f_1)$ and repeat the same argument to find $f_2$. Therefore we have an ascending chain of ideals
$$
(f_0)\subsetneq (f_0, f_1)\subsetneq (f_0, f_1,f_2)\subsetneq \cdots
$$
such that $f_n\in I$ but $f_{n}\notin (f_0, \cdots, f_{n-1})$. This is a contradiction because each ascending chain of ideals should stabilize but the above chain doesn't. This means our original assumption, that $I$ is not finitely generated, is wrong.